# how to open internet explorer windows when clicking a link in chrome or Firefox by php code

Tags: php, browser

how to open internet explorer windows when clicking a link in chrome or Firefox by php code 
Please help me

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can't. There's no means to open a new window in a different browser through PHP. The closest is Javascript's [window.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) function which will open a new window/tab in the current browser instance, but is generally frowned upon, as it's essentially a popup.